# Erlang - How to construct reference(), tref(), socket()... values?

Tags: erlang

The problem is that sometimes I forgot to assign the returned value to a variable.

With pid() variable, it can be constructed by pid(X, Y, Z).

How can we do like that with reference, timer reference, socket, port...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a reference only by using `make_ref/0`. The whole point of references is that "The reference is unique among connected nodes", so if you didn't assign it to anything, there is no way to recreate it. `tref()` is actually a reference, so the same applies.

But in the shell, you can use `v(-1)` to get the return value of the previous command (and `v(-N)` to get the value `N` commands back). Search http://erlang.org/doc/man/shell.html for "v(" to see examples.